# Custom headers per request in RestKit

Tags: ios, http-headers, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to submit a request to the server,using RestKit 0.20.3 which needs different headers depending on some state of the application

i read these posts : [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079644/2136812) [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14219374/2136812)

and they don't help, because this api is not available

how do i add custom headers to RestKit's url requests ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 2 is the correct technique, you just need to use the new API:

```
request = [objectManager requestWithObject: method: path: parameters:];
```

Then create the operation:

```
operation = [objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest: success: failure:];
```

Then push for execution:

```
[objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:];
```

Comment: Just to add to the above, if you are using named routes you can use: request = [objectManager requestWithPathForRouteNamed: object: parameters:] And if you are using Core Data you should use: operation = [objectManager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest: managedObjectContext: success: failure:]